# Unable to load mailparse even with a zz prefix

Tags: php, rhel7

I've read numerous articles stating that mailparse needs to load after mbstring, however, even when prefixing the mailparse with zz, it still has the same issue and I really am at my wits end in trying to figure out why.

Though I still see it in the list of modules.

```
[root@intranet:~]# php -m
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library     '/usr/lib64/php/modules/zz-mailparse.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/zz-    mailparse.so: undefined symbol: mbfl_convert_filter_flush in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
libxml
mailparse
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

in `/etc/php.ini`

`extension=zz-mailparse.so`

Not sure if this is the issue even though I have SSELinux as permissive.

```
[root@intranet:/usr/lib64/php/modules]# ls -lhZ
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       bz2.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       calendar.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       ctype.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       curl.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       dom.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       exif.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       fileinfo.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       ftp.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       gd.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       gettext.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       gmp.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       iconv.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       imap.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       intl.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       json.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       mbstring.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       mcrypt.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       mysqli.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       mysql.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       opcache.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       pdo_mysql.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       pdo.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       pdo_sqlite.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       phar.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       shmop.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       simplexml.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       sockets.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       sqlite3.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       tokenizer.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       wddx.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       xmlreader.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       xml.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       xmlwriter.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       xsl.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       zip.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:lib_t:s0   zz-mailparse.so
```

I am on a RHEL7 server with PHP 5.6.28 and MariaDB 5.5.52

Comment: I suggest opening a case with Red Hat.

Comment: Worth a shot we already pay for support.

Comment: Don't use zz. No one likes zz. So called zombie zappers are obviously sleeping.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? I'm banging my head against the wall with it.

Comment: @magnus - I actually did and it was last year I did it, I and i just purged a lot of stuff and added `remi-php71` repo on the RHEL server and installed php71 and it's version of mbstring and mailparse and I was good to go.  I tried looking at my server history and found nothing but i did find those installs in my yum history.  Where are you stuck right now?  What are your problems?

Comment: @JonWeinraub thanks for the reply. I actually solved the problem myself. Using the `nm` tool to extract dynamic link library names for the modules in the PHP modules directory helped. It was the order of dependencies. Lucky for me, because we're stuck with PHP 5.4 in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you include the module twice. Something similar to:

```
$ /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d # ls -lh | grep parse
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 Feb  7 12:37 20-mailparse.ini -> /etc/php/7.1/mods-available/mailparse.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 Feb  7 13:03 21-mailparse.ini -> /etc/php/7.1/mods-available/mailparse.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here.

The problem is caused by two facts:

1. The `mailparse.so` PHP dynamic link library requires the `mbstring.so` PHP dynamic link library.
2. PHP dynamic link libraries ("extensions") are loaded from both `/etc/php.ini` (and `/etc/php-cli.ini`) **and** the files in the `/etc/php.d` directory *in alphabetical order*.

There are several solutions:

1. Ensure that `mbstring.so` is loaded prior to `mailparse.so` in `php-cli.ini`:

```
extension=mbstring.so
extension=mailparse.so
```

2. If you have either extension in a file in `/etc/php.d`, rename the `.ini` files themselves so that they are ordered.

```
mbstring.so

    extension=mbstring.so

zz-mailparse.so

    extension=mailparse.so
```

3. Load the `mbstring.so` module twice. Note that this produces lots of PHP warnings in the logs which I dislike.

```
mailparse.so

    extension=mbstring.so
    extension=mailparse.so

mbstring.so

    extension=mbstring.so
```